# Is it possible to develop a remote desktop server application?

Tags: android, remote-desktop

I just want to know whether it is possible to develop an Android application that will allow remotely controlling an Android phone in the same way that remote desktop, or team viewer allows control over desktop operating systems. Is it possible on an unrooted phone?

The basic functionlit required to acompolish this is would be the ability to capture the frame buffer and programmatically invoke touch on the device.

Any feedback on this matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You would have to modify the OS in order to get that functionality. It is dissallowed for obvious security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The consensus used to be that it wasn't possible pre-Kit-Kat or without root, but there is a free Android app I came across recently which seems to have figured it out and does exactly what you're asking. It is called Mobizen, and it operates similar to Chromecast or YouTube, pairing the device app with the desktop app (USB) or web-app (Mobile and Wifi).

https://www.mobizen.com/
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rsupport.mvagent&hl=en

How they implemented everything though, I don't know. But it's quite impressive and I would love to get ahold of some source/example code.